# How can I associate a PayPal transaction with a member's account info from my database?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, paypal

I have a registration form on my website where they enter their account info(email, username, password, etc).  After this section are buttons where the user can select free or premium plans.  If the user selects premium, I want to take them to the paypal recurring payment page where the pay for it on paypal.  This is where I am stuck.  I managed to get the entire registration form working, but I need to give the PayPal transaction a user ID based on the new ID for their account created in my database... this way, when the paypal IPN pings my IPN listener URL, I can add a row to my "subscriptions" table with the user's ID.

What's the most efficient way to do this?  I am using PHP and CodeIgniter.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just like you said yourself make a table named 'subscriptions' with some columns like 'id', 'user_id' 'payment-type' etc. Then whenever an user registers and pays you can create a new row with all information needed.